# How much prestige does a gym lose when battling it?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been trying to keep an eye on this for a while now but I don't really understand how it's being worked out.

Obviously the number of Pokemon defeated affects how much prestige is lost. But what are the other factors and how much do they each affect it?

I feel like if you use only one you may get a bonus? What about if you're fighting with others? Does the level of the gym matter? What about if you retreat or lose all your Pokemon half way? Does swapping out Pokemon affect it at all?

Answer (score 10):

A Gym loses 500 prestige per pokemon defeated and 2000 prestige when the entire gym is defeated.  This means that if there is only a single pokemon guarding a gym when you defeat it, it loses 2500 prestige.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that defeating a gym is -1500 prestige and not -2000 prestige

Answer (score -1):

A gym loses 500 prestige per pokemon you defeat. You can repeat this so long as you have a supply of revives and potions until the gym reaches level 0.

Comment: I'm very certain this isn't correct since I generally only need to defeat all the Pokemon once in order to level down a gym which is far more prestige than what you are suggesting.